# How can I associate two different child nodes in different references in a Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm relatively new to Firebase, and I'm trying to avoid layered data by putting user data into two different paths like it says in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/structure-data). So, the plan is for each user to have two different unique identifiers; one node for his or her account information and another node for task boards. So each user should have a node for **information** and another node for **task boards**.

[image]

The problem is that I cannot use the same unique identifier more than once.

This snippet creates the user in database:

```
private void addUser(final String email, String password, final String lastName, final String firstName) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                    //Create a reference for task board ids
                    taskBoardRef = database.getReference().child("taskboard_ids");

                    String boardId = taskBoardRef.push().getKey();
                    Log.i("Check",boardId);

                    //Attach user object to user reference
                    userRef.push().setValue(new Employee(firstName,lastName,email,boardId));

                    //Attach a default task board to the taskboard
                    taskBoardRef.push().setValue(new TaskBoard("Default"));


                    //Create a new SessionManagement instance
                    //Temporarily store user info
                    SessionManagement sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext(),auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                    sessionManagement.createLoginSession();

                    //Go to task activity
                    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TasksActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
}
```

This is the TaskBoard class:
TaskBoard.java

```
public class TaskBoard {
private String taskBoardName;
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users_tasks");
private DatabaseReference refForTaskBoard = database.getReference("user_task_boards");

public TaskBoard(){}
TaskBoard(String name){taskBoardName = name;}
public List<Task> tasks;

public List<Task> getTasks() {
    return tasks;
}
public String getTaskBoardName(){return taskBoardName; }
public HashMap<String, Boolean> addTask(Task task)
{
    HashMap<String, Boolean> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put(task.getName(),task.isComplete());
    return result;
}

public static class Task {
    private String name;
    private boolean complete;

    public Task(){}
    public Task(String name, boolean complete)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public boolean isComplete() {
        return complete;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
userRef.push().setValue(new Employee(firstName,lastName,email,boardId));
taskBoardRef.push().setValue(new TaskBoard("Default"));
```

with

```
userRef.child(boardId).setValue(new Employee(firstName,lastName,email,boardId));
taskBoardRef.child(boardId).setValue(new TaskBoard("Default"));
```

Using the above, you'll be able to use the same `boardId` that you get from the `push()` method in both places.